# Format .net ShortDatePattern to Jquery datepicker dateformat

Tags: asp.net, datepicker, cultureinfo

I need to pick up the local culture from .Net and drop into a javascript variable to pass to jQuery datepicker.

I have used the following based on [Convert .NET DateTimeFormatInfo to Javascript jQuery formatDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138635/convert-net-datetimeformatinfo-to-javascript-jquery-formatdate)

```
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToLower().Replace("yyyy", "yy")
```

This works fine on British, but I cant get info on the returned format for other regions. Will this be sufficient for all regions or will it prevent date pickers from working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker's dateFormat - how to integrate with .NET current culture DateTimeFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531247/jquery-datepickers-dateformat-how-to-integrate-with-net-current-culture-date)